# Is it possible to design a visual and auditory oddball paradigm in Android?

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience, experimental-psychology

I want to design an oddball paradigm to record event-related potential. Is it possible to design a visual and auditory oddball paradigm in "Android"?

Comment: ERPs generally need quite stringent control of timing, which may be challenging in a mobile programming environment (not my expertise though). Even Windows is notoriously bad in timing control at the millisecond level. May I ask why you wish to use Android? Recording ERPs is done in the lab, with the subject pretty much being immobilized in a chair. Hence, deploying a laptop or pc would not be too difficult?

Comment: @AliceD it's worth noting that there are mobile/wireless EEG systems

Comment: @Krysta - are there? That's interesting. But are those likely to be deployed in ERPs?

Comment: They can be assuming sufficient temporal resolution in event codes, which is as you note a problem in mobile settings!  So a bit of a circular problem.

Comment: @AliceD....i have developed a cognitive training module in android. and for assessment also, i wanted to develop odd ball paradigms in android(as i can do programming in android, other software programs such openSesame etc require  programming in python which i do not know). thats why wanted to know if it is feasable to develop oddball pardigms in android).  Visual oddball i think i might be able to develop. but auditory i m not sure.  is there any other way , you can suggest,  where i can design an odd ball paradigm for ERP analysis

Comment: @Krysta.,,, emotiv mobile eeg systems are very popular                       [link](http://emotiv.com/epoc.php)